# Cargo says "test failed, to rerun pass '--lib" - What does it mean?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

What is cargo trying to tell me here with this final message? :

`error: test failed, to rerun pass '--lib'`

Even the Cargo book has test examples showing this exact final line, without explanation. It almost sounds like it is saying, "If you don't pass --lib, we won't rerun the tests" - Does it pull test results from a cache?

If I add "--lib" to my command line, thus: `cargo test --features some_feature --lib`, it doesn't seem to do anything special.

Doing some digging, I found [a Cargo code change](https://github.com/ehuss/cargo/commit/c61efd8c39b58b2af17a3b9663a866fd17d295cd) that seems to be trying to show "{pkg_info}--lib"

So, what is Cargo trying to tell me? Something meaningful, or is it just a bug that confuses new users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message means that in order to rerun the tests that failed, you should pass `--lib`. What `--lib` does is (from the help) "Test only this package's library unit tests". So a library unit test failed, and Cargo is telling you how to rerun only the library unit tests, since you don't need to bother re-running the tests that just passed, but instead usually want to focus on the tests that failed and rerun those only.

Comment: Thanks for that. My cargo.toml mainly builds a bin file, so I didn't understand the reference to 'lib' to run my tests, but it has a '[lib]' section too. All my tests seem to still run with that '--lib' option. Seems I need to understand the build sequence more. quite the learning curve with Rust. Thanks again.